# redirect to jsp page from spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC framework. I got stuck at one point. i want to display another jsp page from my current jsp page.for that i use ajax on client side. I am sharing my code in below. Please help me out to solve this. 
Thanks,

```
 <li>
                                    <a href="" onclick="displayEditProfile();" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                        Edit My Profile </a>
                                </li>
```

my Javascript Function is :

```
function displayEditProfile(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/HappyWorld/displayEditProfile.do',
    data:{
        //sharePost : $('#userPost').val(),
        //"password":$('#passwordId').val(),
        time : new Date(),
    },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',

    success: function(data) {

    },  
error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(xhr+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
}
});
```

}

My controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/displayEditProfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView displayEditProfile(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(" in call.");
    return new ModelAndView("edit_user_profile");

}
```

and my xml configuration for view is:

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
      p:prefix="/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Comment: but why ajax to achieve this?

Comment: so how can i do it??

Comment: check my following answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ajax to redirect.You can directly use

```
     <a href="displayEditProfile"  target="_blank">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                    Edit My Profile </a>
```

if you want to pass some parameters you can submit the form with action=displayEditProfile and have the form fields.

```
  <form action="displayEditProfile" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove @ResponseBody.